# Slideshow in HTML5

Tags: php, database, html, css, slideshow

I want to create an Online Slideshow in HTML5 and CSS where I could browse files in my PC and upload it online. Is that possible without a PHP Database? Sorry about the question , I'm beginning in HTML. Thank you all!

Comment: dont be sorry, but read http://stackoverflow.com/tour before asking again

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the other articles in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting. Thanks

Comment: Browsers will not let you browse arbitrary local directories for security reasons. Uploading will require server-side programming, including a database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Php is a programming language not a database. You do not need a database for a slideshow, however you would use php to upload the images as well as list all the images in a directory. Once you accomplish that, you can pass the images to your slideshow.

You can probably easily implement this script to your webpage.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dirlist/1/